# OpenGL , How to accumulate alpha and use glAlphaFunc to alpha test?

Tags: opengl

`glAlphaFunc(GL_GEQUAL, 0.5)` can display the image where alpha >= 0.5.

Can opengl display the accumulation of  alpha?

Example:

2 images, they will not display some part separately, because alpha < 0.5.

Now some of them overlap, their alpha sum to 0.6, how to display this overlap part?

I try to make a metaball example use opengl, if you have any idea, please please give me some hint.

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you currently do blending?

Comment: GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha,BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha); it can show the aero effect  but can not accumulate the alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would render the images to separate buffer (with Alpha Test off, and adding their alpha). Then, render the buffer onto the screen with Alpha Test.

1. First, create an empty buffer and set it's alpha to 0 for every pixel.
2. Then, render all of your objects on said buffer, using your blend function on colors and adding alpha.
3. Then, re-render the buffen on screen with Alpha Test turned on.

And the answer to the "Can opengl display the accumulation of alpha ?" - yes. You can render alpha as grayscale, for example.

Comment: i have thought this method,but i think it will really slow, because if i render 1000 ball , i will add 1 ball's with other 999 ball's alpha ?

Comment: No, you will be adding the Nth ball's alpha with current buffer value. I will make my answer more precise.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me with glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);

Comment: Please try to give proper explanation of the answer.