# OpenGL , About alpha test and draw bitmap efficient

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

**1 Can we do alpha test at Global?**

```
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glAlphaFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0.7);
```

Use these two functions We can draw a texture and display the image where alpha >= 0.7. My question is if I draw 2 texture some part of them overlap, their alpha sum to 0.7, how to display this part?

---

**2 How to draw a bitmap more efficient**

About question 1, I try some functions in OpenGL, and did not achieve. so I try another way. I set a `map[512][512]`. I first draw all texture on this map and accumulate the alpha myself. If a pixel alpha >= 0.7, I set it color , if not I set white color. At end, I draw the whole map as a texture to the window. Using this method , I can achieve do alpha test at global. but it very very slow.

(This method comes from Bartek Banachewicz at stackoverflow)

Here is my function :

1. init `map[512][512]` all set to zero
2. draw every thing on this map, and accumulate the alpha
3. loop every pixel at map, set them color according there alpha
4. using `glTexImage2D()` to generate texture (I think this may be slow)
5. using `glTexCoord2f` and `glVertex3f` to draw this on the window.

Using this method, I draw about 100 things, It become really slow (about 20 FPS)

**Can I do something to optimize this Method or have another achievement?**

Comment: Since you're citing me - it was only a method. If you implemented it using software (CPU-based) processing, it will of course be slow. The point was to use shaders (or even normal texturing/tests) in both passes. Try using FBO instead of `map[512][512]`.

Comment: Anyway, relevant http://stackoverflow.com/q/11915548/752976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is if I draw 2 texture some part of them overlap, their alpha sum to 0.7, how to display this part?

First, some terminology:

You cannot draw textures *at all*. You can only draw *triangles*, which *may* involve mapping one or more texture to them.

If you are mapping both textures to the triangle, then what you do with their alpha depends on your shader (or if you're not using shaders, then your `glTexEnv` settings). If you're drawing them separately, then you're not drawing 2 textures. You're drawing *one* texture, followed by *another* texture.

Unless you use a blend mode, what the first texture drew *cannot* affect the second. Or the third.

> How to draw a bitmap more efficient

In general, you *don't*. There are ways to make transfering image data more efficient (centering around [pixel buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) for async transfer and [buffer streaming techniques](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming)), but if all you're doing is blitting images, then the correct way to do this is not to create textures every frame.

What you want to do is give OpenGL all the images you ever plan to use, and then use texture mapped triangles (quads) to draw them directly to the screen. This is how it is done in most applications that do 2D blitting.